# C# Windows store app stream mp3 from URL

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have search all over SO and on google.

Im trying to find a example of how I can stream internet radio (mp3) from a Windows Store App.
All the examples I found are small pieces of code that doesn't work.

Can someone explain or show code on how exactly I should do.

I have been trying mediaelement and some others.
I tried this

```
public async void Play()
{
Uri bla = new Uri(string.Format("http://live-icy.gss.dr.dk/A/A04H.mp3.m3u"), UriKind.Absolute);
var uriStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bla);
var uriStream = await uriStreamReference.OpenReadAsync();
nm.SetSource(uriStream, "audio/mp4");
}
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: Which problems do you encounter?

Comment: Just that all the examples dont work.. I think its because some of them are for windows phone, and others are quite old

Comment: We can help u better when u show the code (example) and explain your difficulties with it.

Comment: Which problems do you experience with that code? What doesn't work?

Comment: It build fine and no errors, but it dont play. I tried to change to audio/mp3 in setsource, and also to run nm.Play() after SetSource

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, however I have a working example.

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://live-icy.gss.dr.dk/A/A04H.mp3.m3u");
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage msg = await hc.GetAsync(uri);
await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(await msg.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync(), stream);
stream.Seek(0);
myMediaElement.SetSource(stream, msg.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
```

You must remember to call `Dispose()` on your `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` and `HttpClient` when you are sure you have finished with them. Otherwise you will most likely end up with a memory leak.